# Missing colored area on pdf using itext pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext

[image]

I am editing an existing pdf using itext pdf. While doing this, only a portion of rectangle box is showing as colored and some part is not highlighted.
Looks like some overlay issue is happening here.

The yellow colour is not showing in complete rectangle.

```
    PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getUnderContent(1);
    canvas.saveState();
    canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.YELLOW);
    canvas.rectangle(36, 786, 66, 16);
    canvas.fill();
    canvas.restoreState();
    stamper.close();
```

Comment: Trying to add the image ...

Comment: You add your rectangle to the `UnderContent`, i.e. *under* the existing content of the page which includes the gray background of those two columns. Thus, it is obvious that *"the yellow colour is not showing in complete rectangle."*

Comment: @mkl I also tried OverContent , but then i completely overrides the text. i.e. the text is completely lost behind yellow colour. Ant way to set it a opaque transparency?

Comment: Isn't *"opaque transparency"* a contradiction in terms? That said, you can indeed apply transparency or, even better, the blending mode **Darken** or **Multiply**. First, though, what are your expectations concerning the area where there currently is gray, should the result be a more grayish yellow or the same yellow as where there currently is white?

Comment: @mkl thanks for response. The end goal is to highlight the text on pdf with yellow rectangle box. Yellow color box should highlight the text from left to right. you can see that, in the screen shot while attempting this the middle area is not getting applied with yellow colour along with the text.

Answer (score 2):

To make your task work, you should not draw *under* the existing content (as so that content can simply cover your mark) but instead *over* it. And to make the original content shine through, you should use an appropriate blend mode:

```java
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(1);
canvas.saveState();
PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
state.setBlendMode(new PdfName("Multiply"));
canvas.setGState(state);
canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.YELLOW);
canvas.rectangle(36, 786, 66, 16);
canvas.fill();
canvas.restoreState();
stamper.close();
```

*([MarkContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/MarkContent.java#L41) test)*

You didn't share your PDF, so I had to try with a PDF I have here. Using an appropriately changed rectangle position and size the code marks this

[image: Before]

to look like this:

[image: After]